# convert a .exe to .dll win32 proj & prevent to exit on fatal error

Tags: c++, dll, exe, fatal-error

I'm trying to convert a .exe to .dll proj. that use many other libs & a global macro defined to exit when fatal errors occurred.
do you have an idea to instead of exit, return error number? 
thanks a lot.

Comment: Other than changing that macro? Because changing the macro sounds like the far easier solution.

Comment: yes. this macro used in many method that return void or if return int, caller don't check returned value for error. if want to change macro

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution is to `throw` an exception. However, expect memory leaks. The existing code won't release memory in those fatal cases. Hence, you probably should exit anyway, but at least catching the exception would allow you to save work in progress.